# What's a word for navigating through a labyrinthish group of obstacles to a goal?

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance:

> "I ______ to her, (pushing by the wavy maze of people between us)"

Comment: Maybe ***slogged*** or ***waded*** over to her?

Comment: "Maneuvered," perhaps?

Comment: I think the word you want for the title is "labyrinth**ine**".

Comment: Why not the word in your title, *navigated*?

Comment: *Pushing through* a maze and *pushing by* a maze are two different things. Anyway, you could say *I winded my way to her* or even *wended*, although I'm just throwing that last one   in because I like the verb.

Comment: *labyrinthish is not a word -- it's *labyrinthine*

Answer (score 3):

**Weaved**, is the word I would use.

Definition from [Google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=weaved):

> twist and turn from side to side while moving somewhere in order to avoid obstructions.

---

Usage:

> "I **weaved** my way towards her"

or as @sumeli said, you can use it like:

> "I **wove** my way to her."

Comment: @sumelic I read the article, and if we believe it, weaved is the correct form in this context -- unless he was working on a hand-loom as he progressed towards her.